# Videos on collagePlus

Tags: jquery, css, video

I'm using the jQuery plugin [*collagePlus*](https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus) to build a gallery-like portfolio on a webpage.

I found [this way to replace the images with YouTube videos](https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus/issues/50) and i tried using the code. But, when i used it as it is shown by *nssmart*, the video wouldn't show up with the right dimensions. I sort of solved that by setting both width and height to '100%'.

After that i got two new issues:

1) The caption shows up when the mouse hovers the video, and the caption covers the player's controls.

2) If the window is resized in any way, everything gets messed up - the image wrappers don't adjust their dimensions accordingly and the video player disappears.

The image is like this:

```
<div class='Collage'>
    <div class='Image_Wrapper' data-caption='caption text'>
        <img id='id' src='img.jpg' onclick='loadVideo()'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the function i'm calling once the img is clicked:

```
function loadVideo(){
    $('#id').replaceWith('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
};
```

I tried to insert this line on loadVideo() to solve #1:

```
$('#id').closest('.Caption').css('display', 'none');
```

But it doesn't work, the caption is still there. I also tried using .css('visibility', 'hidden') and .hide(), but no success. I already expected issue #2 since the collagePlus code is built to work with img, but i don't know if there's a way to get around this. How can i solve these issues?

I was using the images as links to the videos on YouTube, but some bosses can be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do these using custom data attributes with some jQuery code.

Create a div inside the *.Image_Wrapper*s, then set a *data-video* attribute with the link for the embedded YouTube video on the img inside them:

```
<div class='Image_Wrapper' data-caption='caption text'>
    <div class='videoContainer'>
        <img src='img.jpg' data-video='https://www.youtube.com/embed/video' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then create two functions, one to place the videos after you click the imgs and another one to resize the videos correctly - you'll use this last one as a callback inside the *collagePlus* function that handles the image resizing "*applyModifications()*".

```
$(".videoContainer > img").click( function() {
    var a = $(this).data("video"),
        b = $(this).width(),
        c = $(this).height();
    $(this).closest(".videoContainer").prepend('<iframe width="'+ b +'" height="'+ c +'" src="'+ a +'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe');
});

function videoResize() {
  $("iframe").each( function() {
    var a = $(this).closest(".Image_Wrapper").width(),
        b = $(this).closest(".Image_Wrapper").height();
    $(this).width(a).height(b);
  });
};
```